# javaCV UnsatisfiedLinkError

Tags: java, eclipse, ubuntu, javacv, unsatisfiedlinkerror

I have a problem with JavaCV.

I downloaded [javaCV-bin](http://code.google.com/p/javacv/downloads/detail?name=javacv-src-20120512.zip&can=2&q=)

and i added .jar file in my project in references libraries on ubuntu

I could worked sample codes which locate in downloaded file

But error is

```
Exception in thread "main" java.lang.UnsatisfiedLinkError: /tmp/libjniopencv_core3835922554849797701.so: libopencv_core.so.2.4: cannot open shared object file: No such file or directory
at java.lang.ClassLoader$NativeLibrary.load(Native Method)
at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadLibrary0(ClassLoader.java:1750)
at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadLibrary(ClassLoader.java:1646)
at java.lang.Runtime.load0(Runtime.java:787)
at java.lang.System.load(System.java:1022)
at com.googlecode.javacpp.Loader.loadLibrary(Loader.java:403)
at com.googlecode.javacpp.Loader.load(Loader.java:342)
at com.googlecode.javacpp.Loader.load(Loader.java:316)
at com.googlecode.javacv.cpp.opencv_core.<clinit>(opencv_core.java:131)
at java.lang.Class.forName0(Native Method)
at java.lang.Class.forName(Class.java:264)
at com.googlecode.javacpp.Loader.load(Loader.java:335)
at com.googlecode.javacv.cpp.opencv_imgproc.<clinit>(opencv_imgproc.java:96)
at java.lang.Class.forName0(Native Method)
at java.lang.Class.forName(Class.java:264)
at com.googlecode.javacpp.Loader.load(Loader.java:335)
at com.googlecode.javacv.cpp.opencv_highgui.<clinit>(opencv_highgui.java:91)
at com.googlecode.javacv.OpenCVFrameGrabber.start(OpenCVFrameGrabber.java:171)
at MotionDetector.main(MotionDetector.java:23)
```

How can i solve the problem?
How can i configure javaCV on ubuntu 11.10 for solving problem.

Thank for helping

Answer (score 0):

The README states under required software:

> *** OpenCV 2.4.0  http://sourceforge.net/projects/opencvlibrary/files/**#

I'm guessing that's the problem.

Comment: Thank you. I want to do just capture a image using webcam in java on ubuntu 11.10. But i have error javacv configuration. i don't understand what i am :)

Comment: You're welcome. I have no knowledge of this library so you'll have to ask another question if you need more information. Remember to always read the README though.

Comment: @user1291468 Don't forget to mark answers as correct by clicking the `tick`.

Comment: But my problem didn't just fix. Maybe user will say how i fix the problem

Comment: not fix the problem same Exception in thread "main" java.lang.UnsatisfiedLinkError: /tmp/libjniopencv_core3835922554849797701.so: libopencv_core.so.2.4: cannot open shared object file: No such file or directory

Comment: Did you install the opencv library then?

Answer (score 0):

dude download library from link:

> https://code.google.com/p/javacv/downloads/detail?name=javacv-0.5-cppjars.zip&can=2&q=

and add library **opencv-linux-x86.jar** to your project

Answer (score 0):

This is come into play when the native library can’t be loaded or
When you try to create a jar file of your program. Since .dll files are mostly written in c/c++ jvm can’t include them in a jar file or gives linkage error when u try to run your program. But for openCV you use this piece to load the dll file successfully.

Just create a java class and copy paste this code and use the method to load the dll file successfully

```java
    /**
     * The minimum length a prefix for a file has to have according to {@link File#createTempFile(String, String)}}.
     */
    private static final int MIN_PREFIX_LENGTH = 3;
    public static final String NATIVE_FOLDER_PATH_PREFIX = "nativeutils";

    /**
     * Temporary directory which will contain the DLLs.
     */
    private static File temporaryDir;

    /**
     * Private constructor - this class will never be instanced
     */
    private NativeUtils() {
    }

    /**
     * Loads library from current JAR archive
     * 
     * The file from JAR is copied into system temporary directory and then loaded. The temporary file is deleted after
     * exiting.
     * Method uses String as filename because the pathname is "abstract", not system-dependent.
     * 
     * @param path The path of file inside JAR as absolute path (beginning with '/'), e.g. /package/File.ext
     * @throws IOException If temporary file creation or read/write operation fails
     * @throws IllegalArgumentException If source file (param path) does not exist
     * @throws IllegalArgumentException If the path is not absolute or if the filename is shorter than three characters
     * (restriction of {@link File#createTempFile(java.lang.String, java.lang.String)}).
     * @throws FileNotFoundException If the file could not be found inside the JAR.
     */
    public static void loadLibraryFromJar(String path) throws IOException {
 
        if (null == path || !path.startsWith("/")) {
            throw new IllegalArgumentException("The path has to be absolute (start with '/').");
        }
 
        // Obtain filename from path
        String[] parts = path.split("/");
        String filename = (parts.length > 1) ? parts[parts.length - 1] : null;
 
        // Check if the filename is okay
        if (filename == null || filename.length() < MIN_PREFIX_LENGTH) {
            throw new IllegalArgumentException("The filename has to be at least 3 characters long.");
        }
 
        // Prepare temporary file
        if (temporaryDir == null) {
            temporaryDir = createTempDirectory(NATIVE_FOLDER_PATH_PREFIX);
            temporaryDir.deleteOnExit();
        }

        File temp = new File(temporaryDir, filename);

        try (InputStream is = NativeUtils.class.getResourceAsStream(path)) {
            Files.copy(is, temp.toPath(), StandardCopyOption.REPLACE_EXISTING);
        } catch (IOException e) {
            temp.delete();
            throw e;
        } catch (NullPointerException e) {
            temp.delete();
            throw new FileNotFoundException("File " + path + " was not found inside JAR.");
        }

        try {
            System.load(temp.getAbsolutePath());
        } finally {
            if (isPosixCompliant()) {
                // Assume POSIX compliant file system, can be deleted after loading
                temp.delete();
            } else {
                // Assume non-POSIX, and don't delete until last file descriptor closed
                temp.deleteOnExit();
            }
        }
    }

    private static boolean isPosixCompliant() {
        try {
            return FileSystems.getDefault()
                    .supportedFileAttributeViews()
                    .contains("posix");
        } catch (FileSystemNotFoundException
                | ProviderNotFoundException
                | SecurityException e) {
            return false;
        }
    }

    private static File createTempDirectory(String prefix) throws IOException {
        String tempDir = System.getProperty("java.io.tmpdir");
        File generatedDir = new File(tempDir, prefix + System.nanoTime());
        
        if (!generatedDir.mkdir())
            throw new IOException("Failed to create temp directory " + generatedDir.getName());
        
        return generatedDir;
    }
```