# Face Detection on images using JavaCV for Android

Tags: android, face-detection, javacv

I am making a face detection app (not real-time) to detect faces in an image on android
I tried using the FaceDetector class in android.media which is good but it isn't very accurate.
so I downloaded JavaCV and java.cpp packages
(with OpenCV v 2.3)
The project runs but gives exceptions:

```
    Thread [<1> main] (Suspended (exception UnsatisfiedLinkError))  
Loader.loadLibrary(Class, String[], String) line: 463   
Loader.load(Class) line: 368    
Loader.load() line: 315 
opencv_core.<clinit>() line: 131    
Class.classForName(String, boolean, ClassLoader) line: not available [native method]    
Class.forName(String, boolean, ClassLoader) line: 234   
Loader.load(Class) line: 334    
opencv_imgproc.<clinit>() line: 96  
Class.classForName(String, boolean, ClassLoader) line: not available [native method]    
Class.forName(String, boolean, ClassLoader) line: 234   
Loader.load(Class) line: 334    
opencv_objdetect.<clinit>() line: 96    
Class.classForName(String, boolean, ClassLoader) line: not available [native method]    
Class.forName(String, boolean, ClassLoader) line: 234   
Loader.load(Class) line: 334    
MyView.<init>(Context) line: 50 
FaceSwAPPerActivity.onCreate(Bundle) line: 35   
Instrumentation.callActivityOnCreate(Activity, Bundle) line: 1047   
ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread$ActivityClientRecord, Intent) line: 1611    
ActivityThread.handleLaunchActivity(ActivityThread$ActivityClientRecord, Intent) line: 1663 
ActivityThread.access$1500(ActivityThread, ActivityThread$ActivityClientRecord, Intent) line: 117   
ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(Message) line: 931   
ActivityThread$H(Handler).dispatchMessage(Message) line: 99 
Looper.loop() line: 123 
ActivityThread.main(String[]) line: 3683    
Method.invokeNative(Object, Object[], Class, Class[], Class, int, boolean) line: not available [native method]  
Method.invoke(Object, Object...) line: 507  
ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run() line: 839  
ZygoteInit.main(String[]) line: 597 
NativeStart.main(String[]) line: not available [native method]
```

and below is my code:

```
import android.app.Activity;
import android.content.Context;
import android.graphics.Bitmap;
import android.graphics.BitmapFactory;
import android.graphics.Canvas;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.view.View;

import com.googlecode.javacpp.Loader;
import com.googlecode.javacv.cpp.opencv_objdetect;
import com.googlecode.javacv.cpp.opencv_objdetect.*;
import com.googlecode.javacv.cpp.opencv_core.*;

import static com.googlecode.javacv.cpp.opencv_core.cvGetSeqElem;
import static com.googlecode.javacv.cpp.opencv_core.cvRectangle;
import static com.googlecode.javacv.cpp.opencv_core.cvPoint;
import static com.googlecode.javacv.cpp.opencv_objdetect.cvHaarDetectObjects;
import static com.googlecode.javacv.cpp.opencv_core.cvLoad;
import static com.googlecode.javacv.cpp.opencv_imgproc.cvCvtColor;
import static com.googlecode.javacv.cpp.opencv_imgproc.CV_BGR2GRAY;
import static com.googlecode.javacv.cpp.opencv_core.CV_AA;
import static com.googlecode.javacv.cpp.opencv_core.IPL_DEPTH_8U;

public class FaceSwAPPerActivity extends Activity {
/** Called when the activity is first created. */
@Override
public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) 
{
super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
//setContentView(R.layout.main);
setContentView(new MyView(this));
}

}
// The cascade definition to be used for detection.
//private static final String CASCADE_FILE = "haarcascade_frontalface_alt.xml";

class MyView extends View {

  Bitmap myBitmap;

public MyView(Context context) 
    {
        super(context);

         Loader.load(opencv_objdetect.class);

         String CASCADE_FILE = "../haarcascade_frontalface_alt.xml";
         BitmapFactory.Options bitmapFatoryOptions=new BitmapFactory.Options();
            bitmapFatoryOptions.inPreferredConfig=Bitmap.Config.ARGB_8888;
         myBitmap=BitmapFactory.decodeResource(getResources(), R.drawable.kidsparty, bitmapFatoryOptions);

        // Load the original image.
         IplImage originalImage = IplImage.create(200, 400, IPL_DEPTH_8U, 1);
        //IplImage originalImage = com.googlecode.javacv.cpp.opencv_highgui.cvLoadImage( imgPath , 1);
        myBitmap.copyPixelsToBuffer(originalImage.getByteBuffer());

        // We need a grayscale image in order to do the recognition, so we
        // create a new image of the same size as the original one.
        IplImage grayImage = IplImage.create(originalImage.width(), originalImage.height(), IPL_DEPTH_8U, 1);

        // We convert the original image to grayscale.
        cvCvtColor(originalImage, grayImage, CV_BGR2GRAY);
        CvMemStorage storage = CvMemStorage.create();

        // We instantiate a classifier cascade to be used for detection, using the cascade definition.
        CvHaarClassifierCascade cascade = new CvHaarClassifierCascade(cvLoad(CASCADE_FILE));

        // We detect the faces.
        CvSeq faces = cvHaarDetectObjects(grayImage, cascade, storage, 1.1, 1, 0);

        //We iterate over the discovered faces and draw yellow rectangles around them.
        for (int i = 0; i < faces.total(); i++) {
          CvRect r = new CvRect(cvGetSeqElem(faces, i));
          cvRectangle(originalImage, cvPoint(r.x(), r.y()),
          cvPoint(r.x() + r.width(), r.y() + r.height()), CvScalar.YELLOW, 1, CV_AA, 0);
        }
        myBitmap.copyPixelsToBuffer(originalImage.getByteBuffer());
        // Save the image to a new file.
       // com.googlecode.javacv.cpp.opencv_highgui.cvSaveImage(args[1], originalImage);
    }
@Override
protected void onDraw(Canvas canvas)
{
    canvas.drawBitmap(myBitmap, 0,0, null);
}

}
```

I just dont know what is the problem please help

Answer (score 0):

Did a quick search and came up with this.  The error looks to be the same even though the format is different.

[javaCV UnsatisfiedLinkError](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10692053/javacv-unsatisfiedlinkerror)

Apparently you have to have the core OpenCV software and libraries installed in addition to its java bindings.

Hope this helps

Comment: the core OpenCV libraries and software are already installed (version 2.3.1) .....

Comment: Its still possible that your program can't find them, did you check that they were where they belong?  Its usually some variation of this that causes the unsatisfied link error

Comment: I have checked but i ll recheck it.....or maybe its a problem with the version.... :s

Comment: Possibly..  What version of the JavaCV bindings are you using?  If its not too much trouble, you should probably update to the latest version anyway, 2.3.1 looks pretty old (~10 months and 2 releases)

Answer (score 0):

The problem seems to be linking the opencv. Have you included opencv\build\x64\vc10\bin in your path variable? Check the link below as well. 
https://code.google.com/p/javacv/wiki/Windows7AndOpenCV